# morphism of monoids and group

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

let $B,C$ be commutative monoids, $A$ be an abelian group and $B \stackrel{b}{\leftarrow} C \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} A$ morphisms of monoids. Let $P$ be the push-out of $A$ and $B$ w.r.t. $C$ in the category of monoids. 
Here my question: Do I get a group homomorphism
$$
P^{gp}\rightarrow A\oplus B^{gp}
$$

Thank you.

Comment: I would rather expect the quotient modulo the image of $C$ in $A\oplus B$ (groupified) on th eright hand side.